# using autohotkey to parse text file

Tags: autohotkey

I need to copy each row of a document that contains the words "make", "model", "year". The words will always be next to each other. I will need each row to be put into a new file named ahk-output.txt.

i.e. raw data:

model honda 
model civic
year 2012

output to file:

honda civic - 2012

I need to repeat for many files found in my documents folder. They are located in the same folder and all copied data will be written to the same file. The documents are long but the words are guaranteed to be in the top 30 rows.

```
Loop, read, C:\Users\vangp.ENTERPRISE\Documents\*.txt, C:\ahk-output.txt
{
    IfInString, A_LoopReadLine, model, FileAppend, %A_LoopReadLine%`n
}
{
    IfInString, A_LoopReadLine, year, FileAppend, %A_LoopReadLine%`n
}
{
    IfInString, A_LoopReadLine, marketing name, FileAppend, %A_LoopReadLine%`n
}
```

Comment: "Are guaranteed to be in the top 30 rows" Does this mean that these words WILL not appear after 30 lines, SHOULD not be changed after 30 lines (even when found) or will be in the first 30 lines for sure and can show up beyond the first 30 lines where they should be changed as well?

Comment: The information will be in top 30 rows definitely. I do not want the script to be wasting time search the whole file as the data I want will not be lower than the top 30 rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to help you since no-one else responded.
Here is a simple beginning, modify to your heart's content.

```
FileDelete, C:\Temp\Results\Extracted.txt
Loop, C:\Temp\Source\*.txt
{
    Loop, read, C:\Temp\Source\%A_LoopFileName%
    {
        IfInString, A_LoopReadLine, model
        {
            StringReplace, CurrentLine, A_LoopReadLine, model, %A_Space%
            StringReplace, CurrentLine, CurrentLine, year, %A_Space%
            StringReplace, CurrentLine, CurrentLine, marketing name, %A_Space%-%A_Space%
            FileAppend, %CurrentLine%`n, C:\Temp\Results\Extracted.txt
        }
        If (A_Index >= 30)
            Break
    }
}
```